# Oracle issue with group by and count query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables from where i am accessing data.

```
1- bulk_prov_master
2- bulk_prov_detail
```

The issue is, I want to get count of users of requests at Request_stamp as well as at Response_stamp.

users is a column in bulk_prov_detail and each request has multiple users.

Right now i have written a query to get request and response time of all the requests. (requests can be same)

**Query**

```
select A.request_batch_id, A.request_stamp, A.response_stamp--, count (DISTINCT b.users)
from bpdata.bulk_prov_master A, bpdata.bulk_prov_detail b
where A.request_stamp > to_DATE('01/09/2015 23', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.response_stamp< to_DATE('01/11/2015 00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.request_batch_id = b.request_batch_id
```

and I am getting following response.

```
265384  1/10/2015   1/10/2015 5:05:23 AM
265384  1/10/2015   1/10/2015 5:05:23 AM
265384  1/10/2015   1/10/2015 5:05:23 AM
265384  1/10/2015   1/10/2015 5:05:23 AM
265384  1/10/2015   1/10/2015 5:05:23 AM
```

Now i want user count from of each time stamp as well.

**UPDATE:**
I have written another query and this time i am getting following response

**Query**

```
SELECT To_CHAR( B.response_stamp , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24') as input, count(A.REQUEST_BATCH_ID), count(DISTINCT A.users)
FROM bpdata.bulk_prov_detail A, bpdata.bulk_prov_master B
where B.response_stamp > to_DATE('01/21/2015 00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and B.response_stamp< to_DATE('01/22/2015 00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.REQUEST_BATCH_ID = B.REQUEST_BATCH_ID
GROUP BY To_CHAR(B.response_stamp, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24');
```

**response**

```
21/01/2015 03   12865   3016
21/01/2015 08   5706    573
21/01/2015 05   1812    182
21/01/2015 04   422     43
21/01/2015 00   8048    2053
```

Now i am getting this data for response_stamp, i want the response_time data where users are same in request_time data

***following is the data of example what i want***

```
request_stamp   requests  users   response_stamp   requests  users
21/01/2015 03   12865     3016    21/01/2015 05    12865      3016
21/01/2015 08   5706      573     21/01/2015 03    12865      3016
21/01/2015 05   1812      182     21/01/2015 05    12865      3016
21/01/2015 04   422       43      21/01/2015 05    12865      3016
21/01/2015 00   8048      2053    21/01/2015 05    12865      3016
```

Comment: oracle. updating my question right now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the best Way is to use a group by like

```
select count(*) as requests, A.request_stamp from bpdata.bulk_prov_master A, bpdata.bulk_prov_detail b where A.request_stamp > to_DATE('01/09/2015 23', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.response_stamp< to_DATE('01/11/2015 00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.request_batch_id = b.request_batch_id group by A.request_stamp.
```

If you want to count different users you must use a subselect:

```
select count(*) as requests, stamp, user from (select A.request_batch_id, A.request_stamp as stamp, A.response_stamp-- (DISTINCT b.users) user from bpdata.bulk_prov_master A, bpdata.bulk_prov_detail b where A.request_stamp > to_DATE('01/09/2015 23', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.response_stamp< to_DATE('01/11/2015 00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24') and A.request_batch_id = b.request_batch_id)
```

Comment: request and response stamp is in same table. and i actually want to know the count of users which entered at response time and the request time of same users as well